# Optimising video storage/encoding on server (J2EE)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, thumbnails, codec, xuggler

Please let me know if this question doesnt belong to stackoverflow so that i can move accordingly.

Objective: 
i) I want to convert mp4 into mov and vice versa.
ii) I want to create thumbnail for the video
iii) Rotate the thumbnail if needed ( by looking at meta data information of image)

Solution I tried until now:
i) (http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/  - Thumbnail
ii) https://www.ffmpeg.org/ - Convert video formats.
iii) Rotation : Java code.

I am able to perform achieve all my objectives by using above solution but in above solution its reading stream 3 times and hence causing performance
issues.

Is there any single library or solution that does all of them but doesn't slow us down and cause performance issues?

Answer (score 1):

The [Libav](https://libav.org/index.html) library would satisfy your requirements. It is the library behind ffmpeg, but by building your own tool on top of the library you can achieve all your three steps in one read of the source stream. The [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libav) for the library has a better overview description than the project homepage.